# Android JobScheduler run only once a day

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

I checkout the JobScheduler API which can be used since Android API level 21. I want to schedule a task which requires internet and runs only once a day or optional once a week (in case of successful execution). I found no examples about this condition. Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: [Use `setPeriodic()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder.html#setPeriodic(long,%20long)) for the timing [and `setRequiredNetworkType()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder.html#setRequiredNetworkType(int)) for the Internet requirement.

Comment: watch this https://gist.github.com/codinginflow/4c85bfb052cd7a92ef816ab1845c669a

Answer (score 20):

Follow a simple example for your question, I believe it will help you:

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<service android:name=".YourJobService"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
```

**YourJobService.java:**

```
class YourJobService extends JobService {
    private static final int JOB_ID = 1;
    private static final long ONE_DAY_INTERVAL = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000L; // 1 Day
    private static final long ONE_WEEK_INTERVAL = 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000L; // 1 Week

    public static void schedule(Context context, long intervalMillis) {
        JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) 
            context.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
        ComponentName componentName =
            new ComponentName(context, YourJobService.class);
        JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(JOB_ID, componentName);
        builder.setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY);
        builder.setPeriodic(intervalMillis);
        jobScheduler.schedule(builder.build());
    }

    public static void cancel(Context context) {
        JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler)
            context.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
        jobScheduler.cancel(JOB_ID);    
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(final JobParameters params) {
        /* executing a task synchronously */
        if (/* condition for finishing it */) {
            // To finish a periodic JobService, 
            // you must cancel it, so it will not be scheduled more.
            YourJobService.cancel(this);
        }

        // false when it is synchronous.
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

After scheduling the job, calling `YourJobService.schedule(context, ONE_DAY_INTERVAL)`. It will only be called when connecting to some network and once inside the internal one day... ie once a day with connection to the network.

**Obs.:** The Periodic job can only be finished calling `JobScheduler.cancel(Job_Id)`, `jobFinished()` method will not finish it.

**Obs.:** If you want to change it to "once a week" - `YourJobService.schedule(context, ONE_WEEK_INTERVAL)`.

**obs.:** Periodic job on **Android L** can be run once at any time in the range you've set up.

Comment: Where to call schedule(). I called it in oncreate() but everytime I open the app the notification shows up as well the periodic isnt working.