# How can I run codes once a day for fragment in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, calendar, sharedpreferences

I found this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MZjIhaMKnlo) and copied (almost) the exact code to assign users some tasks once a day as follows:

```
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int currentDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        SharedPreferences settings = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);
        int lastDay = settings.getInt("day",0);

        if (lastDay != currentDay) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putInt("day", currentDay);
            editor.commit();

            str1 = "oic_" + random.nextInt(76);

            int id1 = getResources().getIdentifier("com.codepath.wmgf8:drawable/" + str1, null, null);

            daily_goal1.setBackgroundResource(id1);
        }
```

The only difference is that I put `this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences` instead of `getSharedPreferences` because I am using `Fragment`.

However, it's assigning random images every time I open the app.

Can someone please help me to figure this out?

*Edit*

I found that activities cannot be delivered in Fragment...

It seems the only way to do this is to entirely create a new activity.

Please let me know if there is another option, though!

Comment: Is this helpful? [Android JobScheduler run only once a day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45724454/android-jobscheduler-run-only-once-a-day)

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem as follows:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int currentDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int currentWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", 0);
        int lastDay = settings.getInt("day",0);
        int lastWeek = settings.getInt("week", 0);

        if (lastDay != currentDay) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putInt("day", currentDay);

            //random
            Random random = new Random();

            //item of the day
            String str0 = IOD();

            //commit to system
            editor.putString("IOD", str0);

            //daily_goals
            String[] str = new String[8];
            str = daily_goal();

            editor.putString("daily_goal1", str[0]);
            editor.putString("daily_goal2", str[1]);
            editor.putString("daily_goal3", str[2]);
            editor.putString("daily_goal4", str[3]);
            editor.putString("daily_goal1_text", str[4]);
            editor.putString("daily_goal2_text", str[5]);
            editor.putString("daily_goal3_text", str[6]);
            editor.putString("daily_goal4_text", str[7]);

            //commit
            editor.commit();
        }
```